# Nginx compare values bigger as

Tags: nginx, lua

How can compare in nginx like (is bigger than):

```
if($a > $b){
    return 503
}
```

The problem:

*...unexpected ">" in condition..*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `<condition>` support for `>` or `<` symbols.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if

But you can use lua to do this:

```
       location / {
        default_type text/plain;
        set $a 2;
        set $b 1;
        content_by_lua_block {
          if ngx.var.a > ngx.var.b then
            ngx.say("a > b")
          else
            ngx.say("a <= b")
          end
        }
    }
```

And make sure you restart nginx on any config changes too.

Comment: If you use content_by_lua_file and lua_code_cache off; then you don't need to restart nginx, which can speed up development a little.